# Websphere MQ Durable Topic Timeout

Tags: java, spring, jms, ibm-mq, spring-integration

I'm connecting to a Websphere MQ topic with a durable subscription using Spring:

```
<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
    channel="springChannel"
    destination-name="wmqTopic"
    connection-factory="connectionFactory"
    destination-resolver="destinationResolver"
    subscription-durable="true"
    durable-subscription-name="myDurableSubscriptionName" />
```

Since this is a durable subscription, I'm concious that whilst the application is not subscribed to the topic in WMQ the messages for next time I connect are piling up either on disk or in memory. I'm concerned that as a result WMQ will run out of either memory or disk space unless a timeout is specified somewhere.

Does anyone know what my options are for specifying the timeout? Should it be in the `message-driven-channel-adapter` or WMQ, or should it be an expiry set on the message before publication?

Comment: Just curios - Why not use a non-durable subscription when you are OK for message expiry?

Comment: @Shashi In the event of failure it would take too long to recover if we didn't expire messages. We would rather lose the messages and recover quicker. Obviously the ideal solution would be to process all the messages quickly but this is not achievable right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> or should it be an expiry set on the message before publication?

Yes.

Comment: Thanks Gary. Can you confirm it's definitely not possible to configure the topic to expire the messages (i.e. a global timeout for any message on the topic) regardless of whether there was an expiry on publication? Also, once disconnected will the durable subscription last forever (until deleted manually) or is there a param in WMQ to remove durable subscriptions if not connected in X timeframe?

Comment: You would have to consult IBM's documentation for that; my answer was from a pure JMS (standard) perspective.